# ASP.Net, jQuery - $(document).ready(function () not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a wizard with a number of steps, for each step I have a user control being added.
For one of the step, I want to run jQuery script on page load, so following is added in user control .ascx file -

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PropertyEntryWizard10HipEpcQuestions.ascx.cs"          Inherits="PropertyInstructionEntryWizard.PropertyEntryWizard09HipEpcQuestions" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/Properties/HipManager.ascx" TagName="hip_manager" TagPrefix="rt" %>

 <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
          alert('HipManager ready');            
        });
 </script>

<h2>EPC</h2>   

<rt:hip_manager ID="ctlHipMan" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Wizard" />
```

But it's not firing on page load,
instead when I do a manual re-load from the browser button, it does get run and I get the alert.

NOTE: I also found out that if I move the script from this user control to main .aspx page, it works fine. My user control is using lots of PeterBlum controls, so I am not sure if any script associated with them is causing the issue.

Any idea, what I am missing?

Thank you!

Comment: open your page in **Chrome** or **Safari**, fire up the **Inspector** (right click somewhere and select Inspect this element) and see if you have in the Console tab javascript errors that are preventing that code to execute.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked in Firebug... therez no error and script is also loaded. Tried in Safari too, but same issue... I wonder how they are being fired when I do a manual reload of the page.

Comment: I think we need to see more of your page to help you out... do you have anything other than jQuery referenced, for example and where is this script block and the jQuery include in the page flow?

Comment: Why don't you try putting the code in the <head> tag?

Comment: can I have two head tags? one is already there in the master page and I want to add the script in user control.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the pageLoad() function instead of  $(document).ready()?

Which one you use really depends on what you are trying to do in the long run with the code, but take a look here as this is a really good explanation of which one you should be using in different situations:

http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/

Comment: +1 Ritchie, that article (and site in general) is a great reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but using pageLoad() didn't make any diff.